# Switching React components

Tags: reactjs

I want to make switching between components. There are two components let's say Component A and Component B. Component A is a Parent to Component B. I can manage switching from A to B on the basis of some state change. Meanwhile, I want to switch back to component A on the basis of some state change in B component. Now, the question is:

Q . I import B component in A. So, should I import A in B also which is child ?
Sounds naive maybe, But I am react beginner.

Meanwhile, I am not sure if its  a good approach? Is there any good way to handle. I have seen some question for switching where third component is involved and rest of the two are imported to it.
Kindly suggest me handling it.

Example:
Component A

```
import B from './B.js';

class A extends React.Component{
constructor(props, context){
        super(props, context);
         this.state = {
                 showB: false
         }
    }
onClick = () =>{
this.setState({ 
            showB: true
            });
}
render(){
return(
{
 this.state.showB ? <B /> : 
<div>
<Button onClick={this.onClick}>VIEW B </Button>
</div>
<h1>I am component A</h1>
)
}

}
```

Component B

```
class B extends React.Component{
constructor(props, context){
        super(props, context);
         this.state = {
                 showA: false
         }
    }
onClick = () =>{
this.setState({ 
            showA: true
            });
}
render(){
return(
{
 this.state.showA ? <A /> : 
<div>
<Button onClick={this.onClick}>VIEW A </Button>
</div>
<h1>I am component B</h1>
)
}

}
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "switching"? Can you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) please? That would make it easier to understand your question and provide an answer.

Comment: @Meana can you please mention some snippet of your code?

Comment: May be you can refer: https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html. With Higher Order Components you can have a single state for both the components and conditionally render them by passing the props.

Comment: @Luze example added

Answer (score 0):

You should pass onClick function to your button, not state.

```
...
<Button onClick={this.onClick}>VIEW A </Button>
...
```

Here is working example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-sanderson-ntu69

Including A in B and B in A is bad idea, because of never ending nesting each other. A includes B, that renders A, That render B, that renders A an so on...

Comment: Yeah, I updated that . It was some mistake i made while writing example. thanks

Comment: attached example

Comment: Is it possible for you to write me your example in my code. It looks promising but I am unable to identify where should I write these function `const A = proops => { } ` etc. plus you are making some use of {useState} also

Comment: const A, and const B - could be exported from outside of index.js file, as standalone components. I've just updated example corresponding your code style https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-sanderson-ntu69

Comment: it is still like importing A and B into some third once, which I don't need. Anyhow, thank you so much for the effort!

Answer (score 0):

You should create a parent component called `C` and in that component you can import both `A` and `B` and use the same logic to show whether A or B. So it should be something like

```
import B from './B.js';
import A from './A.js';

class C extends React.Component{
constructor(props, context){
        super(props, context);
         this.state = {
                 showA: false,
                 showB: false
         }
    }
onClickA = () =>{
this.setState({ 
            showA: true
            });
}
onClickB = () =>{
    this.setState({ 
                showB: true
                });
    }
render(){
return(
{
 this.state.showA ? <A /> : (
<div>
<Button onClick={this.onClickA }>VIEW B </Button>
</div>
)

}
{
 this.state.showB ? <B /> : (
<div>
<Button onClick={this.onClickB }>VIEW B </Button>
</div>
)

}

}
```

**Alternative Approach**
If you don't want to create another component. What you can do is that when you are showing B you don't render any other A component. Only a button that will render in both cases to switch components. It could be something like this:

```
import B from './B.js';

class A extends React.Component{
constructor(props, context){
        super(props, context);
         this.state = {
                 showB: false
         }
    }
onClick = () =>{
this.setState({ 
            showB: !this.state.showB
            });
}
render(){
return(
{
 this.state.showB ? <B /> : (
<div>
/* content of A*/
</div>
)
<Button onClick={this.onClick }>VIEW B </Button>

}


}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes I see it can accomplished by adding third component. But I don't need that. I want A to be my parent component. Is it not  possible without adding third component?

Comment: To clarify you will showB and while showing B none of the A content will be shown right?

Comment: It will cause never ending nesting and errors: A includes B, that renders A, That render B, that renders A again and again...

Comment: I edited my answer @Meana And also creating a 3rd component would be the ideal approach.

Comment: @octobus In your second answer, yes it can work again for 1 way importing...I constantly need to switch between two components depending upon different state  changes. These two components have different buttons to switch and different state conditions also. Anyways, Thanks .

Comment: If you can't use 1 button to switch. You can create a function in component `A` and send this function as a props to `B` and assign to `Button` in `B`. That way you can control the state of `A` and switch. @Meana